# Why does closures associated with Closure class when using static scope?

Tags: php

```
class someScope {
}

$newThis = new someScope;

$closure = function () {
    self::__invoke(); // to check the scope
};

// This is expected behaviour:
$closure(); // Error: Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active. 

$newclosure = $closure->bindTo($newThis, "static");

// Unexpected behaviour:
$newclosure(); // Error: Call to undefined method Closure::__invoke()
```

As you see, for some reason $newclosure associated with Closure class. I expected same error as previous, because as i understand "static" scope means $newclosure takes same scope as $closure.

I tried to check source code but havent found where things went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Because according to https://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php, setting the second parameter ($newScope) to 'static' keeps the current one which is `Closure`. Setting the first parameter ($newThis) only affects the value of `$this`. To bind the value of `self::` to the class of $newThis do:

```
$newclosure = $closure->bindTo($newThis, $newThis);
```

Comment: Is it Closure? Why? $closure has no scope. So $newclosure must to have same scope (no scope).

Answer (score 1):

This is why:

```
if ((scope == NULL) && this_ptr && (Z_TYPE_P(this_ptr) != IS_UNDEF)) {
    /* use dummy scope if we're binding an object without specifying a scope */
    /* maybe it would be better to create one for this purpose */
    scope = zend_ce_closure;
}
// zend_ce_closure - it is Closure class scope
```

When you create closure in non-scope place it has $this = null and scope = null. When you try to bind new $this without setting scope (bind with "static") it will use dummy scope (which is Closure class) instead of using null.